# ¿ Por qué node/express me devuelve un array vacio?

Tags: nodejs

Necesito que me devuelva el total de ingresos de una tabla, para esto desde **node/express** hice esto:

```
export const getTotalAmountByType = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
): Promise<Response> => {

  if (!req.params.operation) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      message:
        "FALTA CONTENIDO EN EL CUERPO"
    });
  }

  try {

    const a = 'select sum(amount) as total from operations';
    const b = 'where type = $1';
    const query = a + b;

    const response: QueryResult = await pool.query(query, [req.params.operation]);
    return res.status(200).json(response.rows);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return res.status(500).json("Internal server error");
  }
};
```

Pero de me vuelve un array vacio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero desde **pgAdminIII** si me devuelve el total

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que **node/express** me devuelva ese total de 377800. ¿Por qué no lo esta haciendo?

Comment: Estoy casi 100% seguro de que te falta un espacio justo después de `as total from operations`, o justo antes del `where`.

Comment: @Trauma de hecho me sorprende que no acabe con un error 500, parece que ese error no lanza excepciones

Comment: @PabloLozano Con Promises me pierdo ... pero su doc indica que debería fallar ... https://node-postgres.com/features/queries

Comment: @PabloLozano supongo que no se ve el error porque el segundo parametro van los callbacks y probablemente lo este tomando de alli

Comment: Gracias por responder! @Trauma le acabo de dar el espacio despues del as total from operations, pero sigue devolviendo un array vacio

Comment: @Claudio ¿ Que es `$1` ?

Comment: $1 toma el valor que le esta llegando por parametro, es decir: si por parametro le envio ingreso, ese $1 = ingreso. no se si me explico bien

Comment: @Claudio Pues la verdad es que ni idea. Solo se me ocurre que `operations` no contenga lo que tu esperas

Comment: si es raro, lo que pasa es que si operations no contiene lo que espero, porque desde pgAdmin me esta devolviendo el resultado.